# Change all Divs color when Clicking [ Javascript ]

Tags: javascript, html, css

I try to write a program to change all div color when clicking.
First, on a single click it changes each Div color  and everything works fine!
The problem comes when I add some code to change all div color when clicking the div element with attribute credit but is not working !!

```js
let x = document.getElementById("container");
let y = x.children;

function myFunction() {
  for (let i = 0; i < y.length; i++) {
    let click = 0;
    y[i].onclick = function() {
      if (click == 0) {
        y[i].style.color = "red";
        click = 1;
      } else {
        y[i].style.color = "blue";
        click = 0;
      }

      //when clicking this div change color of all divs to yellow

      if (y[i].getAttribute("credit")) {
          y[i].style.color = "yellow";
        }
      }
    }
  }
  myFunction();
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <!-- Required meta tags -->
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
  <title>clciks</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="container">
    <div value="one">This is Div 1</div>
    <div value="two">This is Div 2</div>
    <div credit="very good">This is Div 3</div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: You should use `data-value` and `data-credit` as both of those are non-standard attributes for `div` elements

Comment: Each loop through `y`, you are resetting the `click` variable to 0. So it will ALWAYS be 0 on every loop. Move that out of the loop.

Comment: @JeremyHarris `click` is a `let` block scoped variable.  It's not being reset.  A new one is created for each iteration. (provided its in a browser that implements the ES6 functionality)

Comment: Also as can be seen by running the snippet, there is a syntax error around the if conditional at the bottom.

Comment: what is the solution here??

Comment: because whenever i try it is not working

Answer (score 1):

To achieve what you want you should iterate and set color on all the children if the clicked element has 'credit' attribute.
Considering other comments I have renamed the attributes with 'data-' prefix. 
You can either give all div's a class name and iterate that way or you can just iterate on x.children, which ever is best suited for your scenario.

**// update:**
Updated the code to handle additional questions in comments

See working snippet below:

```js
let x = document.getElementById("container");
let y = x.children;

// define your colors here
const colorsMap = {
 "setA": ["red","blue"],
 "setB": ["yellow", "orange"]
};

// generates a function to handle color change for the element
// the color sets specific to each element is defined as data-colors in html
function handleColorChange(ele) {
  const colorset = colorsMap[ele.getAttribute("data-colors") || "setA"];
  const value = ele.getAttribute("data-value");
  const credit = ele.getAttribute("data-credit") || false;
  
  let click = 0;
  
  return () => {
    // change below line if you don't need to loop on colors
    const color = colorset[click % colorset.length];
    click++;
    
    if (credit) {
      Object.values(x.children).forEach(
        function(child) { child.style.color = color; }
      );
    }
    else {
      ele.style.color = color;
    }
  }
}

// attach color changing functions
function myFunction() {
  for (let i = 0; i < y.length; i++) {
    let ele = y[i];
    ele.onclick = handleColorChange(ele);
  }
}

myFunction();
```

```css
.color-test {
 cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <!-- Required meta tags -->
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
  <title>clciks</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="container">
    <div class="color-test" data-value="one" data-colors="setA">This is Div 1</div>
    <div class="color-test" data-value="two" data-colors="setA">This is Div 2</div>
    <div class="color-test" data-credit="very good" data-colors="setB">This is Div 3</div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: how can we change it so that when i click the last div all other div changes color again  @ksankar

Comment: @GoodnessGoodnessChi I've updated the code to handle that scenario as well. In addition the code is now more flexible, loops through colors and you can easily add more colors.

Comment: please explain to me this line....const color = colorset[clic %  colorset.length] ;   i wonder why we use % there? it is necessary to use it?

Comment: That % is so that you will loop through colors, say you have 3 colors in colorset.
`click 1 => 1 %3 =>  1` (use color 1),
`click 2 => 2 % 3 => 2` (use color 2),
`click 3 => 3 % 3 => 0` (use color 0),
`click 1 => 1 % 3 => 1` (use color 1) 
`
Cycles through this way.